# Paypal live url

Tags: paypal

Can anyone tell me what is the paypal live url for this sandbox url,

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

Answer (score 2):

No this is wrong URL

Try this one and its working fine....

https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp

Thanks

Gaurav Agrawal

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`https://api.paypal.com/nvp`